# write pytest test function return value to file with pytest.hookimpl

Tags: python, return, pytest, return-value, benchmarking

I am looking for a way to access the return value of a test function in order to include that value in a test report file (similar to http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#post-process-test-reports-failures).

**Code example that I would like to use:**

```
# modified example code from http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#post-process-test-reports-failures

import pytest
import os.path

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    # execute all other hooks to obtain the report object
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()

    if rep.when == "call" and rep.passed:
        mode = "a" if os.path.exists("return_values") else "w"
        with open("return_values.txt", mode) as f:
            # THE FOLLOWING LINE IS THE ONE I CANNOT FIGURE OUT
            # HOW DO I ACCESS THE TEST FUNCTION RETURN VALUE?
            return_value = item.return_value
            f.write(rep.nodeid + ' returned ' + str(return_value) + "\n")
```

I expect the return value to be written to the file "return_values.txt". Instead, I get an AttributeError.

**Background (in case you can recommend a totally different approach):**

I have a Python library for data analysis on a given problem. I have a standard set of test data which I routinely run my analysis to produce various "benchmark" metrics on the quality of the analysis algorithms on. For example, one such metric is the trace of a normalized confusion matrix produced by the analysis code (which I would like to be as close to 1 as possible). Another metric is the CPU time to produce an analysis result.

I am looking for a nice way to include these benchmark results into a CI framework (currently Jenkins), such that it becomes easy to see whether a commit improves or degrades the analysis performance. Since I am already running pytest in the CI sequence, and since I would like to use various features of pytest for my benchmarks (fixtures, marks, skipping, cleanup) I thought about simply adding a post-processing hook in pytest (see http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#post-process-test-reports-failures) that collects test function run time and return values and reports them (or only those which are marked as benchmarks) into a file, which will be collected and archived as a test artifact by my CI framework.

I am open to other ways to solve this problem, but my google search conclusion is that pytest is the framework closest to already providing what I need.

Comment: A test function doesn't have a return value, and `pytest` ignores them. You can store your custom data in the test function itself, though, e.g. in `request.config`: smth like `request.config._test_results[request.node.nodeid] = mydata`, then access it via `item.config._test_results[item.nodeid]` in hookimpl.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pytest` ignores test functions return value, as can be seen [in the code](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/fd2fb36eacabf283f11ac3a7f09322074c58a57f/src/_pytest/python.py#L165):

```
@hookimpl(trylast=True)
def pytest_pyfunc_call(pyfuncitem):
    testfunction = pyfuncitem.obj
    ...
    testfunction(**testargs)
    return True
```

You can, however, store anything you need in the test function; I usually use the `config` object for that. Example: put the following snippet in your `conftest.py`:

```
import pathlib
import pytest


def pytest_configure(config):
    # create the dict to store custom data
    config._test_results = dict()


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    # execute all other hooks to obtain the report object
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()

    if rep.when == "call" and rep.passed:
        # get the custom data
        return_value = item.config._test_results.get(item.nodeid, None)
        # write to file
        report = pathlib.Path('return_values.txt')
        with report.open('a') as f:
            f.write(rep.nodeid + ' returned ' + str(return_value) + "\n")
```

Now store the data in tests:

```
def test_fizz(request):
    request.config._test_results[request.node.nodeid] = 'mydata'
```

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't obvious to me, so just FYI - you need to put the 2nd chunk of code in a conftest.py file.

Answer (score 8):

Sharing the same problem, here is a different solution i came up with:

using the fixture `record_property` in the test:

```
def test_mytest(record_property):
    record_property("key", 42)
```

and then in `conftest.py` we can use the `pytest_runtest_teardown` [hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtest_teardown):

```
#conftest.py
def pytest_runtest_teardown(item, nextitem):
    results = dict(item.user_properties)
    if not results:
        return
    with open(f'{item.name}_return_values.txt','a') as f:
        for key, value in results.items():
            f.write(f'{key} = {value}\n')
```

and then the content of `test_mytest_return_values.txt`:

```
key = 42
```

## Two important notes:

1. This code will be executed even if the test failed. I couldn't find a way to get the outcome of the test.
2. This can be combined with [heofling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650249/hoefling)'s answer using `results = dict(item.user_properties)` to obtain the keys and values that were added in the test instead of adding a dict to config and then access it in the test.

Comment: I could not get @hoefling's `config` approach to work but this works well and reads natural